# Really simple XML attributes displayed in an HTML table w/ jQuery - this should be easy

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I've got an XML file automatically generated, which I want to display in HTML.

I've taken a jQuery example & expanded it to read all my attributes;

Live example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3755926/jQuery/jQuery_report.html

Is there possibly a timeout error which causes only the column headers to display? I've never had to deal with so much data before. Or is it the number of attributes on each element? Does this syntax only support a single attribute?

```
// Start function when DOM has completely loaded 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

// Open the xml file
$.get("Default.ass",{},function(xml){

    // Build an HTML string
    myHTMLOutput = '';
    myHTMLOutput += '<table width="98%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
    myHTMLOutput += '<th>LookUp</th><th>TurnLeft</th><th>TurnRight</th><th>Flare1</th><th>Flare2</th><th>CutAway</th><th>Bergan</th><th>TurnWind</th><th>Flare3</th><th>HeadWindOffSet</th><th>DisT</th><th>Safe</th>';

    // Run the function for each student tag in the XML file
    //$('AAR_Assessments',xml).each(function(i) {
    $(xml).find("student").each(function(i) {
        LookUpTime = $(this).find("LookUp").attr("Time");
        LookUpAlt = $(this).find("LookUp").attr("Altitude");
        LookUpRes = $(this).find("LookUp").attr("Result");

        TurnLeftTime = $(this).find("TurnLeft").attr("Time");
        TurnLeftAlt = $(this).find("TurnLeft").attr("Altitude");
        TurnLeftRes = $(this).find("TurnLeft").attr("Result");

        TurnRightTime = $(this).find("TurnRight").attr("Time");
        TurnRightAlt = $(this).find("TurnRight").attr("Altitude");
        TurnRightRes = $(this).find("TurnRight").attr("Result");

        Flare1Time = $(this).find("Flare1").attr("Time");
        Flare1Alt = $(this).find("Flare1").attr("Altitude");
        Flare1Res = $(this).find("Flare1").attr("Result");

        Flare2Error = $(this).find("Flare2").attr("Error");

        CutAwayTime = $(this).find("CutAway").attr("Time");
        CutAwayAlt = $(this).find("CutAway").attr("Altitude");
        CutAwayRes = $(this).find("CutAway").attr("Result");

        BerganTime = $(this).find("Bergan").attr("Time");
        BerganAlt = $(this).find("Bergan").attr("Altitude");
        BerganRes = $(this).find("Bergan").attr("Result");

        TurnWindTime = $(this).find("TurnWind").attr("Time");
        TurnWindAlt = $(this).find("TurnWind").attr("Altitude");
        TurnWindRes = $(this).find("TurnWind").attr("Result");

        Flare3Error = $(this).find("Flare3").attr("Error");

        HeadWindOffSetTime = $(this).find("HeadWindOffSet").attr("Time");
        HeadWindOffSetAlt = $(this).find("HeadWindOffSet").attr("Altitude");
        HeadWindOffSetRes = $(this).find("HeadWindOffSet").attr("Result");

        DisTTime = $(this).find("DisT").attr("Time");
        DisTAlt = $(this).find("DisT").attr("Altitude");
        DisTRes = $(this).find("DisT").attr("Result");

        SafeError = $(this).find("Safe").attr("Error");

        // Build row HTML data and store in string
        mydata = BuildStudentHTML(  LookUpTime,LookUpAlt,LookUpRes,
                                    TurnLeftTime,TurnLeftAlt,TurnLeftRes,
                                    TurnRightTime,TurnRightAlt,TurnRightRes,
                                    Flare1Time,Flare1Alt,Flare1Res,
                                    Flare2Error,
                                    CutAwayTime,CutAwayAlt,CutAwayRes,
                                    BerganTime,BerganAlt,BerganRes,
                                    TurnWindTime,TurnWindAlt,TurnWindRes,
                                    Flare3Error,
                                    HeadWindOffSetTime,HeadWindOffSetAlt,HeadWindOffSetRes,
                                    DisTTime,DisTAlt,DisTRes,
                                    SafeError);
        myHTMLOutput = myHTMLOutput + mydata;
    });
    myHTMLOutput += '</table>';

    // Update the DIV called Content Area with the HTML string
    $("#ContentArea").append(myHTMLOutput);
});
});

function BuildStudentHTML(  LookUpTime,LookUpAlt,LookUpRes,
                        TurnLeftTime,TurnLeftAlt,TurnLeftRes,
                        TurnRightTime,TurnRightAlt,TurnRightRes,
                        Flare1Time,Flare1Alt,Flare1Res,
                        Flare2Error,
                        CutAwayTime,CutAwayAlt,CutAwayRes,
                        BerganTime,BerganAlt,BerganRes,
                        TurnWindTime,TurnWindAlt,TurnWindRes,
                        Flare3Error,
                        HeadWindOffSetTime,HeadWindOffSetAlt,HeadWindOffSetRes,
                        DisTTime,DisTAlt,DisTRes,
                        SafeError){ 
// Build HTML string and return
output = '';
output += '<tr>';
output += '<td>'+ LookUpTime +'<br />'+ LookUpAlt +'<br />'+ LookUpRes + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ TurnLeftTime +'<br />'+ TurnLeftAlt +'<br />'+ TurnLeftRes + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ TurnRightTime +'<br />'+ TurnRightAlt +'<br />'+ TurnRightRes + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ Flare1Time +'<br />'+ Flare1Alt +'<br />'+ Flare1Res + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ Flare2Error + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ CutAwayTime +'<br />'+ CutAwayAlt +'<br />'+ CutAwayRes + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ BerganTime +'<br />'+ BerganAlt +'<br />'+ BerganRes + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ TurnWindTime +'<br />'+ TurnWindAlt +'<br />'+ TurnWindRes + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ Flare3Error + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ HeadWindOffSetTime +'<br />'+ HeadWindOffSetAlt +'<br />'+ HeadWindOffSetRes + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ DisTTime +'<br />'+ DisTAlt +'<br />'+ DisTRes + '</td>';
output += '<td>'+ SafeError + '</td>';
output += '</tr>';
return output;
}
```

Comment: Managed to get it working, although not in IE yet. It would seem like I wasn't able to access that top level XML tag so had to create another within it and that worked. If anyone knows the problem with accessing that top level I'd appreciate knowing what thats about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jquery to make your life easier.

This looks a good guide on a AJAX parsing technique:

http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

Comment: Thanks. I saw earlier that jQ can handle this, but wasn't sure if theres a simple fix to what I'd done. I'll take a look at the jQ route :)